# When to close the FileHandler using java logging with a running jetty server

Tags: java, logging, jetty, filehandle

I have a java console application using jetty as a web server, the application will keep running until user close the console window(on Windows OS, it's the cmd window to run `java -jar xxx.jar` command)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();

        // some code to config server

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
```

Also I implemented a log class as a singleton using java logging, so I can using it to log any event in the application.
The problem is, I am using a `java.util.logging.FileHandler` as the log file handler

```
FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler(".\testlog.log");
fileHandler.setLevel(Level.INFO);
logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
```

Whenever I run the application, there will be a `testlog.log.lck` file created along with the log file and won't go away after the app stopped.

I understand this `.lck` file should be gone after the file handler was closed, but I have no idea when and where should I close the `fileHandler` in my case, since my application don't know when it will be terminated by user.

I tried the `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()` but no luck, I assume the addShutdownHook was called so late that the logger object is already be destroyed.

Can anyone please feed me some ideas about how to deal with the leftover `.lck` files along with logs, or where should I call the `fileHandler.close()` in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Let `java.util.logging` and its `java.util.logging.FileHandler` handle that for you.

A typical setup of `java.util.logging.FileHandler` doesn't use a `java.io.File` reference that you control or setup.  The `java.util.logging.FileHandler` uses patterns and rollover behavior to move to new files based on your pattern.  This means the open and active file will be locked, and eventually a new file will be created when the pattern dictates or when the JVM exits.

Comment: but I got .lck file left in log folder everytime I close the console window with X button, the only situation the file will gone is using double ctrl+C.

Comment: Thjen i suspect that closing the console window doesn't kill the JVM.